# How can I represent a relationship of cardinality many to many?

Tags: database-design, erd, many-to-many

I'm trying to design a database for the information shown in the table
below:

[image]

In this regard, let's make the following assumptions:

1. Each *Student* may take many *Courses*
2. Each *Course* may have many *Students*
3. *Student Numbers*, *Course Numbers* and *Advisor Names* are unique
4. *Student Names* and *Course Descriptions* are not unique
5. Each *Student* has one *Advisor*
6. Each *Advisor* may advise many *Students*
7. Each *Advisor* has one *Office*
8. A *Student* can visit with his *Advisor* many times

**My current approach**

So far, I have come up with the following diagramatic representation:

[image]

**The question**

Being that this contains a many-to-many (M:N) relationship, I am confused as to what the association class (or associative entity type) should be.

What would the correct way to represent this relationship be?

Comment: for a many to many relation, you need an extra table which matches studentnumber with coursenumber

Comment: What happens if an advisor has a name change? For example, gets married, gender reassignment, or perhaps just a legal name change. What happens if a course changes it description?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a `Course` table which would just contain the courses and descriptions.

As stated in the comments, you could then have a `StudentCourse` table which had either a surrogate PK, with foreign keys to `Student` and `Course` or a composite PK (StudentNumber and CourseNumber) with the Grade for the student held in it.

Similarly, you could have an `Office` table and link the Office back to the Advisor.  This would allow multiple advisors to have the same office without having to hold the office name multiple times (what if the office name changed for example?).

As also mentioned using the Advisor name as the primary key might not be best, their name could change; you might be better to use a Surrogate key (integer perhaps?) for that.